# Need help with PHP and MySQL…

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multiple-tables

I have a table of songs, some songs are album song, and some are singles... And I have a table of albums...

Songs table cols: `Song_ID, Album_ID, Song_Name, Date_Released, Timestamp_Released`, others...
If the Album_ID is `[null]`, it means the song is a single

Albums table cols: `Album_ID, Album_Name, Song_IDs, Date_Released`, others...

Note 1: there is no `Timestamp_Released` in albums table

Note 2: `Date_Released` is only a day with no time i.e. "2011-06-16"

I'm currently using this query to display a table (in my html/php page) that each row is a single or a album (songs that are in an album are displayed all in one row as album)

```
SELECT 
    IF(Album_ID IS NULL,s.Song_Name,a.Album_Name) as name, 
    IF(Album_ID IS NULL,s.Date_Released,a.Date_Released) as datereleased, 
    s.Timestamp_Released
FROM songs s LEFT JOIN albums a ON (s.Album_ID = a.Album_ID)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2 DESC,1
LIMIT 0,10;
```

The query above order the list of songs and albums according to date and give the albums the `Date_Released` and `Timestamp_Released` of the oldest song in the album...

So my question is how to give the album the `Date_Released` and `Timestamp_Released` of the newest song in it ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried, ORDER BY 2 ASC,1 instead of ORDER BY 2 DESC,1

Comment: That's doesn't do what I want...

Comment: merely out of curiosity, why do songs on an album have different release dates?

Comment: Not the answer but I just want to say that having song IDs in albums table is unnecessary to put it mildly. And you only should have release date for albums. If it's a single it's ok - just add a type to albums table - ep,lp, double lp or single. And how can songs on the same album be released at different times? Just bizarre. Very inefficient design I reckon.

Comment: @horatio & @AR : I just take that possibility... also I'm curios of how can I do it in php and sql :P ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `s.Date_Released, s.Timestamp_Released` write `MAX(s.Date_Released) as Newest_Date_Released, MAX(s.Timestamp_Released) as Newest_Timestamp_Releasd`
**UPDATE**

```
SELECT 
IF(Album_ID IS NULL,s.Song_Name,a.Album_Name) as name, 
MAX(IF(Album_ID IS NULL,s.Date_Released,a.Date_Released)) as datereleased, 
MAX(s.Timestamp_Released)
FROM songs s LEFT JOIN albums a ON (s.Album_ID = a.Album_ID)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC,1
LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: i tried this, but the query doesn't work at all if i do that, i get result with 0 rows...

Comment: did you try merely adding another column for max(foo) instead?

Comment: @Andy: try updated version (note: `GROUP BY 1`, not `BY 1,2`)

Comment: there is a problem, they are still ordered in the table by the date of the oldest song...